# Why http request was redirected to https unexpectedly?

Tags: ios, http, https, wkwebview

I am using `WKWebView` to send some `http` requests. The using code is simple as below:

```
WKWebViewConfiguration* config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webviewFrame configuration:config];

[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString]]];
```

But sometimes, a few `http` requests would be redirected to `https` automatically。The method of these `http` request were `POST`, but would be changed to `GET` after redirecting. Meanwhile the data in the request body was discarded.

During the redirection, the delegate methods `webView:didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation:`, `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:decisionHandler` and `webView:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:completionHandler:` were all not called. Just `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:` was called, two times.

What is weird is that once I set the `websiteDataStore` property of the config to `nonPersistentDataStore`, or remove the app and reinstall, the redirecting does not happen for the same request.

```
WKWebViewConfiguration* config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
config.websiteDataStore = [WKWebsiteDataStore nonPersistentDataStore];
self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webviewFrame configuration:config];

[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString]]];
```

However, it isn't a good idea to use `nonPersistentDataStore` in my project because there are some login-related business.

I want to know why the redirection happens, and is related to the `websiteDataStore`.

Do any other resolutions exist?

Comment: "*I want to know why the redirection happens*" - hard to say without seeing the actual HTTP requests, both when the redirection does and does not happen, to see if there are any differences between them. Maybe there is a cookie or other HTTP header involved that triggers a redirection to HTTPS in some situations but not others.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that it is due to the `HSTS` mechanism. My post request was redirected forcibly to use the https and meanwhile the body data was lost. Someone had posted a question on Apple Developer fourms but no one answered. Here is [the link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/112505). Is there any way to  disable this mechanism for my WKWebView instance?